# Is it possible to get the output of different SQL queries into one table?

Tags: sql

I am pretty new to SQL and I don't know if what I want to achieve is possible at all.
Here is the query:

```
select top 1 ODLN.DocDate as 'First Shipment' from DLN1 inner join ODLN on dln1.DocEntry=ODLN.DocEntry
where DLN1.ItemCode='179768'

select DLN1.ItemCode, DLN1.Dscription, sum(DLN1.Quantity) as 'Delivered' from DLN1 inner join ODLN on dln1.DocEntry=ODLN.DocEntry
where DLN1.ItemCode='179768' and odln.DocDate>='2019-01-01' and odln.DocDate<='2021-07-16'
group by DLN1.ItemCode, DLN1.Dscription


select RIN1.ItemCode, RIN1.Dscription, sum(RIN1.Quantity) as 'Credited' from RIN1 inner join orin on RIN1.DocEntry=ORIN.DocEntry
where RIN1.itemcode='179768' and ORIN.DocDate>='2019-01-01' and ORIN.DocDate<='2021-07-16'
group by RIN1.ItemCode, RIN1.Dscription

select (select sum(RIN1.Quantity) as 'Credited' from RIN1 inner join orin on RIN1.DocEntry=ORIN.DocEntry
where RIN1.itemcode='179768')/(select sum(DLN1.Quantity) as 'Delivered' from DLN1 inner join ODLN on dln1.DocEntry=ODLN.DocEntry
where DLN1.ItemCode='179768')*100 as 'RMA Quote'
```

Like this I will get 4 results (which are correct), but I need them to get in one output. Basically merge them together. I tried with UNION but all I got were errors.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: short answer: yes, of course. In this case, it would be really useful to also add the errors here for right to the subject ideas/solutions. In general, with union / union all (depending on the desired output) you need to be careful on having the same number of columns/expressions on all select statements and of course the datatypes should be the same (or can convert implicitly) across all. Depending on the RDBMS (which you can please also note here), there might be few things to consider (such as having an order by only on one particular select, columns/expressions aliases etc).

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. Well, the error is indeed: "All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists." But in this case I just don't know how I can equalise the expressions. What is RDBMS?

Comment: Union sounds like it's what you want the columns must match though. That result would then be inserted into a permanent table unless you just need a temporary table to store results.

Comment: Don't copy data around between tables, your data will soon become inconsistent. Create a view instead.

Comment: RDBMS (Relational DB Management System).. either MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle etc. In your case you have: first query has 1 column/expression, second query has 3 columns/expressions.. this number has to be the same across all select statements (so if the first query has 1 column then the rest should be the same).

Comment: Alright. Thanks. I'll try.